# To vector with names from dataframe with rownames

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tibble

I have the following vector with names:

```
myvec <- c(`C1-C` = 3, `C2-C` = 1, `C3-C` = NA, `C4-C` = 5, `C5-C` = NA)

C1-C C2-C C3-C C4-C C5-C 
  3   1   NA   5   NA
```

I would to convert it in a dadtaframe/tibble... keeping the names of elements as rowname.

The best way that I found it was:

```
mynames <- names(myvec)
myvec <- myvec %>% 
    as_tibble() %>% 
    mutate(rownames = mynames) %>% 
    column_to_rownames("rownames")
```

How can I to do this in a more efficient way?

Thanks all

Comment: Can you include the output of `dput(myvec)` to make it easier for people to use your example data?

Comment: You can use scan to read space delimited data from webpage copied vectors: `myvec <- setNames( nm= scan( text="C1-C C2-C C3-C C4-C C5-C", what=""), object = scan(text="3   1   NA   5   NA") )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
as.data.frame(myvec)

     myvec
C1-C     3
C2-C     1
C3-C    NA
C4-C     5
C5-C    NA
```

Or

```
data.frame(myvec)
```